# Spring Custom Exception hanlding

Tags: spring-boot, exception

```java
   @ExceptionHandler(RecordAlreadyExistException.class)
        public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAlreadyExistRecordException(
            RecordAlreadyExistException ex, WebRequest request) {

            List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
            details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ErrorResponse errorDetails = new ErrorResponse(
              "Already registered user ? Did you forget your password ? Please contact anemail@gmail.com for all queries", details);
            return new ResponseEntity(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
```

Here is my scenario:
When the user already exists,
it should throw this custom exception.
I get the response code,
but not the body
(i.e. the error details I passed in the response entity are
not displayed in the browser).

Any idea?

Comment: Is your `@ExceptionHandler` defined in a class marked with `@RestController`?
Do you see any exceptions in the logs of you application (other than the one you're handling)?

Comment: While debugging I'm able to see the exception id and even the message but not able to see that in the postman when it hits. i.e. in postman am getting the exact http  error codes but not the added message. If you see the errorrDetails is the one having it but not displayed.